# Create new variable that is linear combination of many other variables

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix( rnorm(100*50,mean=0,sd=1), 100, 50))
```

I want to create a new variable `y` that is the sum alpha_i*V_i with i from 1 to 50 and where alpha is a random number drawn from a uniform distribution (0,1).

What is the best way of doing this? Can I do it with `mutate` and `dplyr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
 df1$newvar <- as.matrix(df1) %*% v1
```

Or

```
 df1$newvar <- rowSums(sweep(df1, 2, v1, FUN='*'))
```

Or as suggested by @Frank based on the [`post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279075/efficiently-computing-a-linear-combination-of-data-table-columns/19279500#19279500)

```
 df1$newvar <- Reduce(`+`,lapply(seq_along(v1),function(i)df1[[i]]*v1[i]))
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix( rnorm(100*50,mean=0,sd=1), 100, 50))
 set.seed(48)
 v1 <- runif(50)
```

Comment: `sweep` also coerces to `matrix`, I guess. eddi suggested `Reduce(\`+\`,lapply(seq_along(v1),function(i)df1[[i]]*v1[i]))` when I asked almost the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19279500/1191259

Comment: @Frank Thanks, in this case the `sweep` output is a data.frame, but  I guess `lapply` would be fast for big datasets.