# Computing squared residual in regression row-wise in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a `data.table` with columns `X1`,`X2`,`X3`,`Y`. For each row, I would like to treat the entries in `X1`,`X2`,`X3` as vector of length 3,  take the inner product with a fixed vector say `beta` of length 4, subtract the result from the entry in`Y`, square the result, and either output the final result for every row (or save it as another column).

After much research, I came up with this

```
dat[, (Y-sum(.SD*beta))^2, .SDcols=c(1:3)]
```

which does not work as expected.

Bonus point #1: Doing this with 3 replaced by a general `n`.

Bonus point #2: Suppose I have a `grp` column with group indices and I want to average these residual squares by group.

Comment: Next time, consider including a complete reproducible example like Gregor has done.

Comment: @Frank, will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `y` is the first column of your data table `dat` and the rest of the columns are predictors. This works for bonus 1.

```
mat = as.matrix(dat[, x1:x3, with = F])
pred = cbind(1, mat) %*% beta
dat[, rss := (pred - y)^2]
```

For bonus 2:

```
dat[, mean_by_grp := mean(rss), by = grp]
```

---

To avoid the matrix conversion, you could do this:

```
dat[, pred := beta[1] + beta[2] * x1 + beta[3] * x2 + beta[4] * x3]
```

writing out the inner product.

---

### Complete reproducible example

```
set.seed(47)
dat = data.table(replicate(4, rnorm(5)))
setnames(dat, c("y", paste0("x", 1:3)))
dat[, grp := c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B")]
beta = 1:4

mat = as.matrix(dat[, x1:x3, with = F])
pred = cbind(1, mat) %*% beta
dat[, rss := (pred - y) ^ 2]

dat[, mean_by_grp := mean(rss), by = grp]
dat
#             y          x1          x2          x3 grp       rss mean_by_grp
# 1:  1.9946963 -1.08573747 -0.92245624  0.67077922   A 10.565250    7.064164
# 2:  0.7111425 -0.98548216  0.03960243 -0.08107805   A  3.563078    7.064164
# 3:  0.1854053  0.01513086  0.49382018  1.26424109   B 54.512843   38.263204
# 4: -0.2817650 -0.25204590 -1.82822917 -0.70338819   B 56.558929   38.263204
# 5:  0.1087755 -1.46575030  0.09147291 -0.04057817   B  3.717840   38.263204
```

Comment: OK, thanks. Is there a better way? `pred` is something calculated outside the data.table. It should be a natural way to just pass "x" and "y" for every row to a function that operates row-wise. I don't want to convert data.table to a matrix.

Comment: This is the better way. Matrix multiplication is highly optimized. Operating row-wise is the slow way to do this.

Comment: OK... I suppose I could do something like `mat = as.matrix(dat[, 1:3, with=F])` for avoid turning the whole thing into a matrix first.

Comment: OK... the non-matrix conversion approach is not generalizable. It makes me somewhat sad if there is no elegant way of doing the row-wise operation.

Comment: In general though, matrix multiplication is something linear algebra packages are tuned for. You're not going to be able to improve on that. Though you could switch the library R is compiled with. See, e.g., [Faster R through better BLAS](https://www.r-bloggers.com/faster-r-through-better-blas/).

Comment: Row-wise is completely the wrong way to go. You've heard how R is good with vectorization, right? Doing it row-wise is disabling vectorizaton.

Comment: Yes. There is just too much effort to vectorize and it often leads to rather obscure code . From a high-level programming standpoint, it is natural to have fast row-wise operation. I am at that point in life, where I prefer to have readable natural code (and speed) at the same time. (Developments in the Julia community are appealing for this reason.) Sorry for the rant!

Comment: By the way, I don't seem to be able to combine the two steps into `dat[, mean_by_grps := mean((pred - y)^2), by=idx]`. This produces something else.

Comment: Well, perhaps you should create a reproducible example. Works fine for me with the one I cooked up. I'll add it.

Comment: Oh, this is in fact what I have tried `dat[, mean((pred - y)^2), by=idx]`. The version without creating the column does not work, the one I wrote seems to work. This is strange.

Comment: Another way of avoiding matrix conversion is `Reduce`, as in eddi's answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19279500/