# How to compute the linear combination of different columns within R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table and want to take a linear combination of the columns. 
How should I do it?

The setup

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(1)

DT <- data.table(A = rnorm(10),
                 B = rnorm(10),
                 C = rnorm(10),
                 D = rnorm(10),
                 coefA = rnorm(10),
                 coefB = rnorm(10),
                 coefC = rnorm(10),
                 coefD = rnorm(10))
```

I can do the following:

```
DT[, sum := A*coefA + B * coefB + C * coefC + D * coefD]
```

Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Given your question, No there is no better way

Comment: In this instance, you're probably better off working with matrices. Here is one way in base R. ` myMat <- as.matrix(DT)` to convert to a matrix and then `rowSums(myMat[, 1:4] * myMat[, 5:8])` to compute the dot product.

Comment: Those are not linear combinations. In case anyone lands here based on the title, the proper ref is my question, I guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279075/efficiently-computing-a-linear-combination-of-data-table-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is

```
DT[ sum := Reduce(`+`, DT[, 1:4] * DT[, 5:8])]
```

Or using `.SD`

```
DT[, sum := Reduce(`+`, .SD[, 1:4] * .SD[, 5:8])]
```

---

Or we can do

```
nm1 <- names(DT)[1:4]
nm2 <- paste0("coef", nm1)
DT[, sum := Reduce(`+`, Map(`*`, mget(nm1), mget(nm2)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

With [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html):

```
DT %>% mutate(sum = A*coefA + B * coefB + C * coefC + D * coefD)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're needing a better method because you may not always have 4 of each, the following will work as long as the ordering is correct for adding E,F,G;coefE,coefF,coefG...

```
coefcols <- names(DT)[grepl("coef", names(DT))]
valucols <- names(DT)[!grepl("coef", names(DT))]
DT[, sum := apply(DT[, ..valucols] * DT[, ..coefcols], 1, sum)]
```

Edit: After reading @lmo's comment, I realized that the last line can be simplified using `rowSums`:

```
DT[, sum := rowSums(DT[, ..valucols] * DT[, ..coefcols])]
```